# incomplete output ms access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, max, average

```
SELECT temp.hhid, temp.country, temp.max_prod, temp.max_area, gen.price_seed, gen.qty_seed, gen.price

FROM (SELECT hhid, country, MAX(area) AS max_area, max(total_prod) AS max_prod FROM gen GROUP BY hhid, country)  AS temp, gen

WHERE (((temp.hhid)=gen.hhid) And ((temp.country)=gen.country) And ((temp.max_prod)=gen.total_prod) And ((temp.max_area)=gen.area))

ORDER BY temp.hhid;
```

Why do some of the results were not seen?

I have atleast 100 hhid , each one has 3 area  , 3 productions , quantity of seed , price etc ...
all of the hhid was shown in the ouput query except for 1 hhid ,

what might be wrong ?

Comment: What's this got to do with .htaccess?

Comment: Consulting my crystal ball I see...that one of the rows doesn't match the selection criteria. Unfortunately, said crystal ball is in need of a clean so it might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the maximum of `prod` and the maximum of `area` are rarely in the same row.

You should also learn to use explicit `join` syntax.  A simple rule:  never use a comma in the `from` clause.

This may be what you want:

```
SELECT temp.hhid, temp.country, temp.max_prod, temp.max_area, gen.price_seed,    
       gen.qty_seed, gen.price
FROM gen INNER JOIN
     (SELECT hhid, country, MAX(area) AS max_area, max(total_prod) AS max_prod 
      FROM gen
      GROUP BY hhid, country
     ) AS temp
     ON temp.hhid = gen.hhid AND temp.country = gen.country 
WHERE (temp.max_prod = gen.total_prod or temp.max_area = gen.area)
ORDER BY temp.hhid;
```

I left the `WHERE` clause in, because MS Access has strange restrictions on joins.  Logically it should go in the `ON` clause, but I'm not 100% sure that Access accepts that syntax.

Comment: your code has worked yet it still gave me the same output  , the missing 1 or 2 hhid is still missing , your code and my code provides the same output

Comment: @bentetres . . . Are you sure you have an `or` in the `where` clause?  This code should output every non-NULL `hhid` and `country ` combination at least once.

Comment: oh .. sorry I changed the or to and .. can you explain to me , why does using and give me some missing outputs ? while or gives me complete answers?

Comment: @bentetres . . . Like I say in the answer, the rows that have the maximum of `prod` don't necessarily have the maximum of `area`.  With `and`, a row has to match both conditions.